# How to get absolute url with different domain language prefix

Tags: 7, uri, i18n-l10n

What is the best way to get absolute url with correct language prefix?
The `url()` function accepts language parameter but it seems that it is not using it to generate the prefix - only to get translated alias. I don't care about aliases - I need correct domain prefix.

When I'm on `http://en.example.com/something` and use this code:

```
<?php
$all_languages = language_list();
url('something-else', array('language' => $all_languages['nl'], 'absolute' => true));
?>
```

I will get this: `http://en.example.com/something-else` (**en** prefix).

How can I get this: `http://nl.example.com/something-else` (**nl** prefix).

Comment: Problem is - URL doesn't know what's on the other end. It can be node, it can be view, it can be a page created by module... and most of these does not have language defined. So [`url`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7) is not allowed to base it's choices on the target's language. How could it when target usually does not have any?

Comment: @Mołot but then what is the point of providing translated alias (by using `language` parameter) if you are still redirecting user to a different language version than the alias language?

Comment: It's not so easy. There are 3 languages that takes part in the process. Language of a node, language of a GUI and language of the alias. Only the third is always available (even if it's always `undefined`), so only the third is taken into account by `url()`. I never said it's good, right?

Comment: @Mołot I don't want the `url()` to know language of the target element. That is not the point of my question. I would only want it to set the prefix specified by the `language` parameter. After all I am providing language different than current `$base_url` not without a reason :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the `url()` function will create links like `http://nl.example.com/something-else` (note the **nb** prefix) BUT only for specific languages configuration. This will work correctly only if I set appropriate domain for each language here: `/admin/config/regional/language`.

By default the field *Path prefix language code* is set to language code (*nl* in this case) and *Language domain* is empty.

Now since I am using **DOMAIN** prefix for language selection, and not the **PATH** prefix, then for each language I should set language domain instead of path prefix.

For some weired reason Drupal insists on filling only one of those fields, but consequently fills *Path prefix language code* by default even if language detection is set to **domain**.

Answer (score 0):

This was pulled from my theme file, but as long as you have access to $node and $language, it will do the trick:

```
<?php
    if (isset($node))
    {
?>
<div class="language-switcher">
        <?php
            $nodes = translation_path_get_translations("node/" . $node->nid);
            $path  = "";
            if ($language->language == "en")
            {
                if (array_key_exists("nl", $nodes))
                {
                    $path = drupal_get_path_alias($nodes["nl"], "nl");
                }
        ?>
        <a href="http://nl.example.com/<?php print $path; ?>">Change to NL</a>
        <?php
            }
            else
            {
                if (array_key_exists("en", $nodes))
                {
                    $path = drupal_get_path_alias($nodes["en"], "en");
                }
        ?>
        <a href="http://en.example.com/<?php print $path; ?>">Change to EN</a>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
</div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

The URL's are hard coded with the path information calculated.

Comment: I know that I can manually create links with correct prefixes, but that's not the point :)

Answer (score 0):

I format my urls like this.

```
 $order_url = url('user/' . $params['order']->uid . '/orders/'. $params['order']->order_id, array(
'absolute' => TRUE, 
'language' => (object)array(
  'language' => 'lang-key',
)
  ));
```

We can see this is reflected in the url function below.

```
$language = isset($options['language']) && isset($options['language']->language) ? $options['language']->language : '';
$alias = drupal_get_path_alias($original_path, $language);
if ($alias != $original_path) {
  $path = $alias;
}


}
```